# Что-то не то с поиском по именам функций

Tags: дефект, поддержка, поиск

Почему в первом запросе ничего не найдено?

Why there is nothing found with the first query?

[`SetBufferSize`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SetBufferSize) vs [`user:178988 is:a [C#] console`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+is%3Aa+%5BC%23%5D+console)

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: добавь еще текстом запрос. Забавно, но "Console.SetBufferSize" все-таки находит что-то

Comment: @Grundy, добавил.

Comment: [К сожалению, об этом уже давно известно](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105766/339911).

Comment: Вот так поиск [работает](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Console.SetBufferSize+user%3A178988).

Comment: Видимо индексатор текста разбивает его на слова не считая точку разделителем. Возможно это легко настраивается.

Comment: @avp судя по дате вопросов по ссылкам, что я привёл, это либо не очень легко, либо - недостаточно востребовано. Может быть есть смысл объявить конкурс на упомянутом FR. Ознакомьтесь ещё с ответами [тут](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100656/339911).

Comment: Да. Но в любом случае, у нас же есть гугл!